# MSI Installer and Required Radio Button Selection

Tags: radio-button, windows-installer

I'm using VS 2010 and need to make a change in an MSI installer.
I'm not that familiar with the installer creation -- it seems very limited.

I needed to add a new dialog that pops up and asks the user to select one of two possible installation directories.  The dialog is the "RadioButtons (2 buttons)" dialog.

Depending on which radio button you select, the ButtonProperty sets TARGETDIR to either:

```
[AppDataFolder]MyInstall
```

or

```
[ProgramFiles64Folder]MyInstall
```

I have the DefaultValue for the button set to [ProgramFiles64Folder]MyInstall

I've got everything working -- at least when the user selects one of the radio buttons.

The problems are:

- The default radio button isn't preselected when the dialog is displayed and it's possible for the user to advance to the next screen without selecting one of the radio buttons.  How can I prevent that?
- When the default value is set to something like [ProgramFiles64]MyInstall, on uninstall I get an error that it could not access the network location [ProgramFiles64]MyInstall -- even if that is not the location where the files were installed.  If the path for the DefaultValue is a fully expanded absolute path, then there is no error.

Answer (score 0):

With this code you van preselect the radiobutton: radiobutton.Checked = true

Comment: Sorry -- I don't use the MSI installer in VS much, but when building installers it involves setting properties of pre-configured dialogs.  I don't see where I am able to add any code for the dialog.